# Implementing Eclipse WorkbenchAdvisor class for a eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am writing an eclipse plugin and I want to implement a "expiration checker" to disable my plugin once a certain date is reached.

I understand that in order to disable the bundle, I need to turn it into `UNINSTALL` state (FYI - I got this from here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/210006/). Furthermore, I will need to do this in preStartup() by implementing the WorkbenchAdvisor class (from `org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor`)

I found this answer which has contains everything I need to know (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11726335/2851950) EXCEPT I couldn't find `IApplication` or `WorkbenchAdvisor` under my plugin.xml's dependencies page.

Do I need install additional plugins from somewhere? What I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: That answer is talking about what to do when you are creating your own Eclipse RCP. In that case you write your own `IApplication` and `WorkbenchAdvisor`. If you want to plug in to an existing Eclipse you can't change the `preStartup` method.

Comment: hmm I see. How do you suggest I implement this expiry feature? Is it possible to implement the `IApplication` and `WorkbenchAdvisor` classes and `super` everything (so it behaves like Eclipse) but override the `preStartup` method?

Comment: No, an existing Eclipse RCP (such as Eclipse itself) already has an `IApplication` and `WorkbenchAdvisor` which you can't change. In any case in a standard Eclipse the user can open the OSGi console and start any disabled plugins.

Comment: Hmm ok, you have a point, how would you propose that I implement such a feature? It just needs to be a basic mechanism that disables my custom plugin once a certain date has passed. My date source is from a remote server.

Comment: I would just put checks in to the plugin which display a message when it has expired rather than trying to disable it.