# WorkbenchWindowAdvisor#postWindowCreate() never fired

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm currently migration an Eclipse RCP application from 3.0 to 4.4.
Due to the migration Eclipse added some menu entries which I want to get rid off using this approach [Remove "File, edit,...etc" menus from Eclipse RCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774138/remove-file-edit-etc-menus-from-eclipse-rcp-application). Therefore I am calling the method `postWindowCreate()` in my class that extends `WorkbenchAdvisor` and implements `IPerspectiveListener`, but the method is never called.

I've looked up something about this and found out that there **was** a bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=363807

Since I am now using Eclipse 4.4, this bug should be fixed and the method should be called, but it doesen't. The bug was fixed for version 4.3. Is there any information that the bug recurred in version 4.4 or is it because the application was originally developed in Eclipse RCP 3.0?

I also tried to call `openIntro()` out of curiosity, but this method isn't called too.

If this is a bug, is there any workaround? Due to the fact that the application was written in Eclipse RCP 3.0 I can't use commands ect. or those new fancy features of Eclipse RCP 4.x.

Comment: The question mentions both `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` and `WorkbenchAdvisor` both of which have a `postWindowCreate`. Please clarify which one you are using.

Comment: do you define your own application? then visit http://stackoverflow.com/a/11726335/2691625

Comment: I am using the method `postWinowCreate()` of the class `WorkbenchAdvisor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the case, as I mentioned in the comments, I am using the method `postWindowCreate()` of the class `WorkbenchAdvisor`. Unfortunately, I didn't know that there is another class with a method of the same name. The method I need to use has the signature `postWindowRestore(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer)`, but I used `postWindowRestore()`, so I didn't actually override the method I need to use. After adding the parameter it works fine.

Thank you for the advice.